# Best way to parse large XML document in Jython

Tags: java, python, xml, jython, xom

I need to parse a large (>800MB) XML file from Jython. The XML is not deeply nested, containing about a million relevant elements. I need to convert these elements into real objects.

I've used `nu.xom.*` successfully before, but now that I've switched from Java to Jython, the library fails with the following message:

> The parser has encountered more than
>   "64,000" entity expansions in this
>   document; this is the limit imposed by
>   the application.

I have not found a way to fix this, so I probably have to look for another XML library. It could be either Java or Jython-compatible Python and should be efficient. Pythonic would be great, `nu.xom.*` is simple but not very pythonic. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I was going to suggest BeautifulSoup, but this appears to run inexplicably slowly under Jython.

Answer (score 4):

Sax is the best way to parse large documents.

Sounds like you're hitting the default expansion limit.
See this note:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4843787

You need to set System property "entityExpansionLimit" to change
the default.

(added) see also the [answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097823/jython-and-the-sax-parser-no-more-than-64000-entities-allowed)

Answer (score 3):

Try using the SAX parser, it is great for streaming large XML files.

Comment: I have tried `xml.sax`, now I am running into the following error: `xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:1:1: The parser has encountered more than "64,000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the application.`

Comment: @clstaudt: Why accept an answer that gives you such an error message?

Comment: Because the suggestion itself is reasonable, and the error message is a separate issue. Of course, there are other reasonable suggestions now, and there is probably not a single answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

Does jython support `xml.etree.ElementTree`? If so, use the `iterparse` method to keep your memory size down. Read [this](http://effbot.org/elementtree/iterparse.htm) and use elem.clear() as described.

Comment: It appears Jython does not support etree. There is a project [here](http://code.google.com/p/jython-elementtree/) to address this, not sure how current it is.

Answer (score 0):

there is a **lxml** python library, that can parse large files, without loading data to memory.
but i don't know if i jython compatible